# Как разобрать html-файл без сторонних библиотек?

Tags: парсер, java, html

Надо разобрать html-файл без сторонних библиотек. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Если в PHP то подойдет функция:
    file_get_contents


Comment: не php не катит )

Comment: А на чем нужно?

Comment: `file_get_contents` тоже не катит)

Comment: Разве она каким-либо образом парсит html ? IMHO она просто считает часть файла в строку.

Comment: ну в тегах написано java, можно на c/c++, в крайнем случае python..

Comment: Считать файл или урл в строку это уже не парсинг называется? О_о

Comment: Что значит распарсить? Нужно достать оттуда что-то конкретное? Если до, то регулярные выражения. Если нужно работать с html как некой иерархией объектов... то тут врятли что-то можно быстро написать без библиотеки

Comment: @minority это никогда не называлось парсингом. Считать - это считать, "спарсить хтмл" - обычно значит превратить текст в дерево объектов/массивов. Парсинг вообще - преобразование текста в структуру данных.

Comment: @Sasha121 в принципе надо достать из любого html файла весь текст, который находится на странице.

Comment: [грамматика](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/web/html/appa_02.html) у HTML достаточно простая, можно написать обычный лексический парсер.

Comment: То есть вам нужно достать из исходного кода html-файла весь текст, который заключен между тегов (+ некоторые отдельные случаи, когда текст находится внутри значений параметров тегов).
Регулярка подойдет, думаю...

Comment: может ли кто привести более полную информацию о лексическом парсере или как это сделать регулярными выражениями ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример использования (простой, взят из аналогичной темы)

```
final String WORD = "[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(WORD);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(externalText);//указываем свой текст
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Данный кусок кода выводит найденые слова тексте в которых встречаются символы a-zA-Zа-яА-Я. Как составить шаблон регулярки можно почитать в JavaDoc.
Ключевые классы в JavaDoc (Pattern и Matcher).

Comment: ну и будьте готовы что на поиск сложных выражений будут использоваться сложные регулярные выражения.

Comment: ок, спасибо, чувствую это будет не так легко..

Comment: Не так уж и сложно. Пример с PCRE(перловская регулярка) (ищем все, что не тег)

    $reg = '/>([^<]*)</';

=)

Comment: наверно) посмотрю..

Answer (score 1):

неужели кто-то запрещает пользоваться сторонними библиотеками?! 0_о

Comment: ну мне надо разобраться...